# Trouble setting Watson Dialog profile variables

Tags: ibm-watson

I am trying to update some Dialog profile variables via the watson-developer-cloud library.  The client_id variable seems to be ignored, and is being set to a random number. As a result, the profile variables are not being set.  This is the endpoint in my API that is supposed to do the update:

```
app.put('/update', function(req, res) 
   {
   setHeaders(req,res); //set up headers for CORS 
   var parms=req.body;
   parms.dialog_id=dialogId;
   console.log("Processing PUT /update...");
   console.log("Setting: ",parms);
   dialog.updateProfile(parms,function(err, results)
      {
      if (err)
         {
         console.log(err);
         res.status(500);
         res.send(err);
         }
      else 
         {
         console.log('Update returning: ',results);
         res.send(results);
         }
      });
   });
```

and this is a sample value for parms (shown here after JSON.stringify(parms):

{"client_id":12345,"dialog_id":"4a6e3699-10ab-4703-86bb-0b74384aaf94","conversation_id":245895,"name_values":[{"name":"CPE_Name","value":"Tracey Moon"},{"name":"CPE_Name","value":"Kellogg"},{"name":"CPE_StateTerritory","value":"California"}]}

Is this a bug in the watson-developer-cloud library?`enter code here`

Comment: According to the documentation all you need to pass in as parms are the client_id and the name_values - {
  "client_id": 4435,
  "name_values": [
    {
      "name": "string",
      "value": "string"
    }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is apparently a bug in an earlier version of the watson-developer-cloud package. Running 
`npm install watson-developer-cloud@latest` as described in [this post](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/244980/issue-with-dialog-updateprofile-in-nodejs-always-c.html) seems to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Going off the swagger doc here:
https://watson-api-explorer.mybluemix.net/swagger.html?url=/listings/dialog-v1.json#/

I would hit the following endpoint:
https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/dialog/api/v1/dialogs/7eb167d5-f581-40d3-b91a-ad9c142282ad/profile

with the following in the body:
{
  "client_id": 155351,
  "name_values": [
    {
      "name": "Name",
      "value": "Mitch"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: I just ran two tests which set some profile variables. One was using the Postman tool which goes directly to the API, and the other was using the watson-developer-cloud library.  The variables were set properly in the Postman case but they were not set at all when using the library.  Moreover, the library consistently returns a different client_id than the one used when initiating the call, and using the Dialog tool to query on that returned client_id results in a "not found" error.  There is two possible explanations; either I'm doing it wrong or there's a bug in the library. Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

```
Here's a code snippet which does the getConversation to get a client id and then an updateProfile to set a profile var:


var watson = require('watson-developer-cloud');
var dialogid = <dialog_id>;
var clientid = '';
var dialog = watson.dialog({
  username: <username>,
  password: <password>,
  version: 'v1'
});

dialog.conversation({dialog_id: dialogid}, function (err, dialogs) {
  if (err)
    console.log('error:', err);
  else{
    console.log('Started conversation with dialog id ' + dialogid + '.');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(dialogs, null, 2));
    clientid = dialogs.client_id;
}
});

dialog.updateProfile({ client_id: clientid, dialog_id: dialogid, name_values: [{"name":"Topic","value":"Education"}]}, function (err, dialogs) {
  if (err)
    console.log('error:', err);
  else{
    console.log('Set profile variable "Topic" to "Education".');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(dialogs, null, 2));
}
});
```

The above code works for me. Hope it helps!